# Android кол-во работающих сервисов

Tags: android

Делаю проверку сервиса, живет или завершился

```
 ((ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningServices(int);
```

Интересно, система разве не знает сколько у ней запущенно сервисов, зачем в методе getRunningServices(int), я должен угадывать int=?

Как можно узнать количество работающих сервисов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно угадывать. Просто используйте достаточно большое число. Система не вернет больше, чем их есть на самом деле.

Но нужно понимать, что этот метод не предназначен для каждодневного использования, о чем и явно указано в документации:

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.

То есть, переводя на русский - для отдадочных целей или для программ, которые управляют сервисами. Но никак не для программ, которые хотят проверить, работает ли их сервис.

Сервисы нужно проверять по функционалу. То есть, есть запрос к сервису и Вы ожидаете определенного ответа. Если ответа нет - сервис не работает.

Но есть особые случаи. К примеру, если сделать правильный IntentService и он выполнил все свои задачи, то он завершится. Но как только ему будут посланы новые задачи - он продолжит работу. В тот момент времени, когда он свои задачи выполнил, но новых нет он и работает и не работает одновременно (как известный кот) для вызывающей программы.

Comment: Спасибо!
я правильно понимаю, когда выполняется startService(intent), но сервис в данный момент запущен, тогда ничего не происходит? Если так, тогда почему увеличивается startID в onStartCommand()?

Comment: судя по [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))

> if it is running then it remains running.

и там же

> Note that calls to startService() are not nesting: no matter how many times you call startService(), a single call to stopService(Intent) will stop it.

Поэтому сервис будет продолжаться.

startId просто указывает, сколько было попыток запустить сервис.  Он нужен для метода stopSelfResult. Таким образом, если Вы запустили сервис и ещё кто то запустил, а потом решили остановить, то сервис проигнорирует это.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все прояснилось.